# What private key does MobaXterm use by default?

Tags: ssh, authentication, mobaxterm, private-key

What private key does MobaXterm use by default, and can I change it? I read through the documentation, found nothing on what the default key that is used. I know there is the `C:\Users\<me>\.ssh` directory, with a public and private key pair. But its not clear what is used. Unlike `ssh` in Linux I cant just run `ssh -vvvvv` to see more output. I also tried enabling `DEBUG3` in sshd to see if I could see which public key was passed but, it only shows signatures not the actual public key.

Can someone confirm which private key is used by default for MobaXterm?

Comment: There isn't a default private key. You most certainly should be able to create a verbose SSH connection both on the client side and the server side

Answer (score 1):

Based on the result of MobaXTerm agent the terminal start to test private keys sorted alphanumerically. I my case below the sequence is:

1. ESDCA
2. RSA

[image]